# Adding column with defaults without retrofitting value

Tags: postgresql, oracle, mariadb, default, alter-table

If I have a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    address VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO customers(id,address)
VALUES (1,'Here'),(2,NULL);
```

I know I can add an additional column with a default as follows:

```sql
ALTER TABLE customers
ADD more VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'etc';
```

In PostgreSQL, MariaDB, SQLite and Oracle, when I do this the default is retrofitted to all columns. However I don’t want that to happen, since not all of the customers actually have an address.

In Microsoft SQL, the default is only retrofitted if the clause `WITH VALUES` is added.

How can I get the others *not* to retrofit the default?

Comment: Add column first. Modify Column and set default. Checked in MySQL, pretty sure will be the same for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PostgreSQL you can do it in two steps, first add the new column and second set the new default for the column:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    address VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO customers(id,address)
VALUES (1,'Here'),(2,NULL);

-- step one:
ALTER TABLE customers
ADD more VARCHAR(255) ;
-- step two:
ALTER TABLE customers ALTER COLUMN more SET DEFAULT 'etc';
-- test:
SELECT * FROM customers;
```

Comment: OK, I have also tested this technique with MariaDB and Oracle. Oracle uses a different syntax for the default. SQLite doesn’t support altering a column, as far as I can tell, so I’ll have to find a different technique. Thanks for this one.